# Conditional formatting in Google sheet for finished/due tasks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have built a simple task tracker in Google sheet.

There is column B handling the status (In progress, Done) and Due date column C.
I have created to formulas: exact match for B that sets the color to green and date before today for C that sets the red color.

The problem is that they work independently. Red color is displayed for C even when B is Done.
And each rule highlights different column.

[image]

Text is exactly Done

[image]

Date is before `=today()`

[image]

How to make the date formatter ignore the past dues when the task status is set to Done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned

> exact match for B that sets the color to green and
> date before today for C that sets the red color

Try the following formula under `Custom formula is`

```
=AND(C3<TODAY(),B3<>"Done", C3<>"")
```

[image]

*(Do adjust ranges to your needs)*

Comment: Wow, good trick. But Sheets does not like the formula, it says there is an error. I wonder why. I remember that working with functions in localized Excel was a pain in *ss. I hope that Google is smarter and does not localize function names.

Comment: Well, I had to convert a comma to semicolon as separators

Comment: There is a trouble that the cell reference is fixed to the second row, and the third row is still comparing C2 and B2. How can I apply the condition to the current row of the range?

Comment: *"had to convert a comma to semicolon as separators"*. Correct. Because that depends on your locale.   *"There is a trouble that the cell reference is fixed"* Sorry I don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: The conditional formatting rule is the same for all cells in the range: =A(C2<>"";C2<DNES();B2<>"Hotovo")
So the rule for C3, C4, C5 .. C34 is always:
=A(C2<>"";C2<DNES();B2<>"Hotovo")
But it should be for C3
=A(C3<>"";C3<DNES();B3<>"Hotovo")
and for C34
=A(C34<>"";C34<DNES();B34<>"Hotovo")
I do not want to edit the rule for each row individually.

Comment: You need to apply it **once** for the whole range. See the image

Comment: I had to select the range again and then it applied to all cells. Thank you. And do not worry, I do always upvote and accept solutions.

Comment: Glad I could help. *"do not worry, I do always upvote and accept solutions"* Just trying to keep the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets?tab=Unanswered) down